# Is it possible to loop a test in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

So I have a thread group set to run for 30 seconds with simple HTTP sampler. Basically the test just sends a GET request to HTTP server for 30 seconds.

Is it possible to have the same test restart again once it has finished based on a predetermined amount of times. So say i want the test to rerun itself 5 times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

It is possible with `Run Time Controller`.

I assume you have set the 30 seconds duration in the Thread Group scheduler.

Change the test plan as given below.

- Thread Group - loop count should be 5 (no of times should be repeated)
- Add a `Run time controller` - seconds should be 30
- Move all the samplers, other controllers (whatever you had under the Thread Group) under the `Run time controller`.

Now this setup will the run the test 5 times - for 30 seconds each time.

---

**Option 2:**

You can use a bat/sh file to rerun the same test again and again in a loop if you are running the test in `Non-GUI` mode.

Comment: Right I set the the scheduler of the thread group to 30 seconds.